# JSON.stringify API returns 415 (.net & angular)

Tags: .net, angular, api, http-status-code-415

I'm running into a bit of trouble on a POST request from my angular front to my .net API.

Here is the code on the front:

```
    [...]       
    this.uploadFile(JSON.stringify(jsonobject));
    }

    uploadFile(file)
    {
        this.files.push(file);
        this.uploadService.uploadjsonresponse(file, "JsonFilterResponse").subscribe();
    }
```

and the post request:

```
    public uploadjsonresponse(file, apiname) {
         return this.httpClient.post(this.SERVER_URL + apiname, file);  
    }
```

and finally the .net code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/JsonFilterResponse")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(4_000_000_000)]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.EnableCors]
    public IActionResult JsonFilterResponse([FromBody] string jsonresult)
    {
        try
        {
            if (jsonresult != null)
            {
                Response.Body.Flush(); // http response
                return Ok(); // server response
            }
            else
                return NotFound();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
```

The Json object is correct (checked on the console) and so is the API address. The API is returning a 415 that I can't seem to shake. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is jsonobject? How is it look like ?

Comment: It looks something like this: {"xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx":{"0":"*"}} when I log the data being sent in the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who may be wondering, I found the answer! Replace:

```
[FromBody] string jsonresult
```

with

```
[FromBody] JsonElement jsonresult
```

and use

```
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonresult);
```

to interpret the result!

Answer (score 1):

try without using `[FromBody]`

```
public IActionResult JsonFilterResponse(string jsonresult)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I do this, my API is called but the string passed is null... And then I get a 404.